# 415 Unsupported MediaType for Content-Type = Mulitpart/form-data

Tags: java, rest, soapui, jersey-client

I have a REST API which ONLY ***@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)*** and does not ***@Consume*** any MediaType.

Even still when I am consuming this REST API by creating an **HTTP Request** where **MediaType** is being set to **multipart/form-data**, I am still recieving:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

in raw **HTTP Response**.

However, when I am setting **Content-Type** to **application/json**, which this REST API ***@Produces***, I am getting a proper **HTTP Response**.

Below is the **REST API Annotations:**

```
@POST
@Path("/somePath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject addDocument(AddDocBean addDocBean) {
...
```

> *"Now why do I want to send **Content-Type** as **Multipart/form-data**?"*

That is because I am using this service to upload a file to the server and the file is to be sent in a **BASE64** format.
Now the size of file is about **20Mb** which I have been suggested is better sent as **multipart/form-data**

But HTTP server is unable to process this request returning **ERROR 415 Unsupported MediaType** in response.

REST client being used : **SoapUI 5.4.0**

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- @Produces on Server Side corresponds to Accept: Header on the Client Side.
- @Consume on Server Side corresponds to Media-Type: Header on the Client Side.

The API snippet you showed doesn't specify any explicit **@Consume** annotation and hence defaults to plain/text. And hence when you send the Header of application/multipart with your request you get Unsupported Media Type

You need to add an explicit 
**@Consume("MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA")** // something similiar to this over your API to make your addDocument() method to support the form data that you are sending.

Comment: Can there be multiple @Consumes annotations for one API?

Comment: Yes. AFAIK you can have a comma seperated list of MediaType enums

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrpv/. Yes you can have multiple values there

Comment: Though I forgot to mention this in question above but I had tried putting @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) , I have tried the same again just now and I am getting the same 415 http error!!

Comment: Code Snippet:

 @POST
    @Path("/somepath")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject addDocument(AddDocBean addDocBean) {

Comment: Are you also sending Accept: application/json with your request ?

Comment: No. Only MediaType as multipart/form-data

Comment: Please add header Accept: application/json also along with your request

Comment: Still the same but I have observed an Accept header as Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

Comment: Accept: and Accept-Encoding: are different headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169081/discussion-between-harshvardhan-solanki-and-piy26).